# How to remove item selection border of QTreeView

Tags: python, pyqt, qtreeview, qtstylesheets

I have a QTreeView widget and I want to remove the item selection border.
I tried using the **border** property in the **item: selected** sub-control but it does it for the complete item (image + string). But the border for the item still appears in the string part when item is selected. Is there any property or subcontrol that I'm missing?

Screenshot of the page:

[image: Screen shot of the page]

```
QTreeView{
    background-color: #323232;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #9e9e9e;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: "Roboto";
}
QTreeView::item{
    border: none;
}
QTreeView::item:hover, QTreeView::item:selected{
    border: none;
    background-color: #424242;
    color: #bdbdbd;
}
```

Like properties selection-color or selection-background-color is there any selection-border property?

Comment: Try with `QTreeView::item:hover:pressed`

Comment: I found it the property is outline: none